# What's the different between the Java and Clojure code?

Tags: java, clojure, netty

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); // (1)
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(
                            new 6MessageDecoder(),
                            new LoginHandler());
                }
            })
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128
            )          // (5)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)

    // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
    ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); // (7)

    // Wait until the server socket is closed.
    // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
    // shut down your server.
    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
} finally {
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

I write it in clojure:

```
(let [bossGroup (NioEventLoopGroup.)
      workerGroup (NioEventLoopGroup.)
      bootstrap (ServerBootstrap.)]
  (.. bootstrap
      (group bossGroup workerGroup)
      (channel NioServerSocketChannel)
      (childHandler
        (proxy [ChannelInitializer] []
             (initChannel [ch]
               (.. ch
                   (pipeline)
                   (addLast
                     (MessageDecoder.)
                     (LoginHandler.)
                     ))
               )))
      (option ChannelOption/SO_BACKLOG, (int 128))
      (childOption ChannelOption/SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
      (bind (int 8080))
      (sync)
      (channel)
      (closeFuture)
      (sync)
      ;(childHandler (ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>.))
      )
  )
```

The code written in clojure can run,but when i test it:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It doesn't work. However, the Java code can work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: (bind) seems worked. when i run the clojure code again,it prompts:com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: "Address already in use" means that some other process is already listening on port 8080. Don't run two programs at the same time which want to listen on the same port.

Comment: I run the code written in clojure for the second time,I mean the (bind 8080) seems worked in the first time.But I can't telnet the 8080 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the reason:
In clojure java's variable arguments is not well supported.(From my point of view.)
so，
    (addLast
                         (MessageDecoder.)
                         (LoginHandler.)
                         )
is not the correct syntax to call

```
addLast(ChannelHandler... handlers) `
```

netty complains " method not found",but it catches the exception and prints a warning use log4j.I had not seen this warnning before because log4j is not configured.

the out put:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

means the binding and listenning is worked.

now it worked with this code:

```
(.addLast
                 (.pipeline ch)
                 (doto (make-array  ChannelHandler 2)
                   (aset 0 (MessageDecoder.))
                   (aset 2 (ServerHandler.))
                   )
                 )
```